# PHP preserve .jpg metadata on upload from client to server

Tags: php

Scenario:  A Photo Editor person prepares .jpg image files on his client computer, including specifying IPTC metadata Copyright, Description and Byline values on each image.  Images must then be uploaded to server via a PHP-based image upload web page.  Problem: Metadata is stripped during the upload by PHP processes! (Note: If images are uploaded via FileZilla FTP, the metadata arrives intact and can be read by PHP code.)

I've considered using ImageMagick processes instead of the default GD library, but both show no metadata on the uploaded image.  I've considered EXEC(ExifTool...), but it has the same problem -- it will only look at the server's copy of the image that has already been stripped. The metadata cannot be extracted into hidden form fields on the client computer and then rejoined to the image file by PHP because (again) PHP only looks at the server-side file copy, and the metadata has already been stripped by the time it arrives.  I also wish to avoid storing the images as a blob in a MySQL database.  That's why I'm trying to use metadata in the first place, so the Photo Manager can do all image prep off-line and encapsulate the caption, copyright and byline info inside the image file itself and expect it to travel unmolested within the image.  (I was quite dumbfounded to discover that PHP assumes it should strip metadata during image uploads with no recourse!)

Is there a way with PHP to perform an FTP-based file transfer using PHP code?  I'm open to this or any other way to get the server copy of the file to include the original metadata in its copy of the imageA .  TIA

PS -- I have not included code snippets because frankly I have not been able to figure out how to do so in this forum -- yet!

PROBLEM SOLUTION:  File uploads using the HTML FORM tag rely on a special input type "file".  When this is used, all sorts of magical things happen, including an immediate upload of the file to the server to a temporary file in a /tmp/ directory.  I originally thought that it was during this upload from client to server that the metadata was being stripped.  It is not -- I was able to verify that the uploaded temporary file still contained the metadata.

My problem was what I did with the temporary file to put it into its final folder.  ANY process (GD image extension) that modifies the file in any way will immediately strip the metadata.  This is in compliance with metadata standards, since the modified image is no longer the original image and much of the original image's metadata would no longer be accurate!  Calling the move_uploaded_image() function WITHOUT altering the image beforehand copied the temporary image to its final destination completely intact.

Obviously if you NEED php to massage the image before sending it to its final destination, it will NOT preserve the metadata.  In my case, all such massaging is done by the Photo Editor before uploading.

Comment: You could always get the metadata from javascript on the clientside and send it as post data.

Comment: You could try using PHP exec() to call curl (a unix tool for ftp). I do not know if it has the same issues or not. Perhaps there is some argument that will preserve the meta data if it does not happen automatically. See http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html

Comment: Thanks for your speedy advice, Diffster and fmw42.  In the intervening three hours I've solved the problem.  I'll add corrections to my initial post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself while waiting for others to weigh in.  See my original post's PROBLEM SOLUTION section at the end for details.  Thanks to all who looked at my question!